# What is the difference between docker exec -ti and docker exec -it?

Tags: docker

I am newbie with docker, I was reading few of things and I realized some one using `-it` and someone `-ti`.

So I want to know what is the difference between `docker exec -ti my_container` and `docker exec -it my_container`.

Comment: There is no difference. Both pass the `-t` and the `-i` flag, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @tkausl thanks, i got it but what is actual meaning of -i and -t i see at docker website but i am not getting this

Comment: @Pankaj -i is for interactive (Keep STDIN open even if not attached) and -t for tty (Allocate a pseudo-TTY)

Comment: Please update your question if the order of -it and -ti is not the actual issue.

Comment: interchanging flags would ot affect any of the standard apps in linux.
ls -lrth would give the same result for any order of lrth

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference. `-it` is just a shorthand way of specifying the two flags `-i` and `-t`, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/):

> Single character command line options can be combined, so rather than typing `docker run -i -t --name test busybox sh`, you can write `docker run -it --name test busybox sh`.

The `-t flag` assigns a pseudo-tty or terminal inside our new container and the `-i flag` allows us to make an interactive connection by grabbing the standard in (STDIN) of the container.

Since these boolean flags can be specified in any order, `-ti` is equivalent to `-it`.

This is a very common feature of Unix-y command-line tools.

Comment: thanks @mbj i got it but what is actual meaning of -i and -t i see at docker website but i am not getting this